# "Revert this Commit" & "Roll Back to this Commit" on Github desktop for Mac

Tags: git, github, rollback, github-for-mac

I was watching a [course](https://www.lynda.com/GitHub-tutorials/GitHub-Web-Designers/162276-2.html) about using Github. There was "Revert this Commit" & "Roll Back to this Commit" options in the version which the instructor was using.

[image: The screenshot of video]

The latest version is a bit different and I cannot find those options. Could someone help me about this, please?

Comment: I mean, I'd argue that you should really be learning command-line `git` (which is much more powerful than the desktop version), but whatever...

Comment: @SebastianLenartowicz Thanks for your advise! I'll learn it! ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The roll back option has been removed. you could find the revert commit in the following picture.

[Revert Commit Option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQK7P.png)

And roll back now is UNDO.

[Undo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHFP9.png)

Comment: I'm just curious... Why roll back has been removed?

Comment: I think it may try to avoid accidentally roll back the entire repo. The rollback option allows you to rollback several commits and leave no trace. The undo only allows to roll back one commit each time.